# php set variable value in instantiating class

Tags: php, oop

How do I set a value or call a method in the class that instantiated me?  See code below

```
class Father {
    public $foo = '';
}
class Son {
    function setFoo($value){
        //this is the part that I need
    }
}

$father = new Father();
$father->son = new Son();
$father->son->setFoo('bar');
echo $father->foo; //I want it to now be 'bar'
```

Comment: This doesn't actually make sense; *Son* isn't actually a child of *Father* in your example, it's an attribute ... more like a leg than offspring. It's also an undeclared public attribute - which could be embarrassing in the local swimming pool.

Comment: Use your imagination and rename `Father` and `Son` as you wish; let's say A and B.  My question is, if B is an attribute of A, how can a method in B, called from A, modify another property (foo) in A?

Comment: The `Son` object is a self-contained *thing* that shouldn't know anything about the object that contains it; replace `Father` with `Car` and give it the property `$engine` (instead of `$son`) ... `Car::$engine` should know nothing about `Car::$colour` and shouldn't be able to affect it; that's what I meant by it not making sense. Of course if the engine blows up, that would affect the car colour - but I think that would be dealt with as an `Exception` ;)

Comment: @CD001 - `shouldn't know anything about the object that contains it` was what I needed to know.  Thanks.  I realize I've dealt with this before, and this makes sense.

Answer (score 1):

One answer recommends inheritance, which makes sense in a father son way. However, if you don't want that, perhaps the dependency injection (constructor injection) method is what you are looking for.

```
<?php

class Father 
{
    private $son;

    private $foo = '';

    function getFoo()
    {
        return $this->foo;
    }

    function setFoo($value)
    {
        $this->foo = $value;
    }
}

class Son 
{
    private $father;

    public function __construct(Father $dad)
    {
        $this->father = $dad;
    }

    function setFoo($value)
    {
        $this->father->setFoo($value);
    }
}

$father = new Father();
$son = new Son($father);

$son->setFoo('bar');

echo $father->getFoo(); // 'bar'
```

Check it out here https://3v4l.org/hUQve

Answer (score -2):

Your child class needs to inherit from the parent.

```
class Father {
    public $foo = '';
}

class Son extends Father {
    function setFoo($value){
        //this is the part that I need
        $this->foo = $value ;
    }
}
```

Comment: @delboy1978uk, you are correct. I misread his code. He wants the `Father` to have `Son` as a property.

Comment: tbf inheritance definitely sounds reasonable however, especially as we are dealing with parent/child relationships

Comment: This is not extension, this is instantiation as a property.  I understand extension but want a property.